# How can I dynamically increase a number in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, increment

I want to add number dynamically and aiming the outputs as follows.

```
<li data-id="id-1".. > ...</li>
<li data-id="id-2".. > ...</li>
<li data-id="id-3".. > ...</li>
<li data-id="id-4".. > ...</li>
<li data-id="id-5".. > ...</li>
<li data-id="id-6".. > ...</li>
```

I tried this, but it does not work.

Views:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$image_num; $i++){
      foreach($images as $image){
        echo "<li data-id=\"id-".$i."\" data-type=\"".$image['class']."\">\n<img src=\"".base_url().$image['thumbnail']."\" width=\"128\" height=\"128\" />\n<strong>".$image['name']."</strong>\n<span data-type=\"size\">".$image['shortdesc']."</span></li>\n";
            }
        }
```

If there are two images, it repeats twice, if there are three, it repeats three times and so on.

I have the following controller and model.

Controller:

```
function quicksand(){
    $data['header']='Quicksand';
    $group = 'quicksand';
    $data['image_num']= $this->MQuicksand->getNumRowsByGroup($group);
    $data['images']= $this->MQuicksand->getProductsByGroup($group);

    $data['module'] = 'welcome';
    $this->load->view('general/quicksand_temp',$data);
    // $this->load->view('welcome/public/quicksand_view',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getProductsByGroup($group){
     $data = array();
     $this->db->where('grouping', $group);
     $this->db->where('status', 'active');
     // $this->db->orderby('name','asc');
     $Q = $this->db->get('omc_product');
     if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        $num_rows = $Q->num_rows();
       foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
         $data[] = $row;
       }
    }
    $Q->free_result();    
    return $data; 
    return $num_rows;
 } 


 function getNumRowsByGroup($group){
     $data = array();
     $this->db->where('grouping', $group);
     $this->db->where('status', 'active');
     // $this->db->orderby('name','asc');
     $Q = $this->db->get('omc_product');
     if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        $num_rows = $Q->num_rows();

    }
    $Q->free_result();    

    return $num_rows;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you don't care about the array key, you can just use that:

```
foreach($images as $elem => $image){
  echo "<li data-id=\"id-".($elem + 1)."\" data-type=\"".$image['class']."\">\n<img src=\"".base_url().$image['thumbnail']."\" width=\"128\" height=\"128\" />\n<strong>".$image['name']."</strong>\n<span data-type=\"size\">".$image['shortdesc']."</span></li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if I get the question right you just want to increase the number. best thing is to keep it one loop like this:

```
$count = 1;
foreach($images as $image){
    echo "<li data-id=\"id-".$count."\" data-type=\"".$image['class']."\">\n<img src=\"".base_url().$image['thumbnail']."\" width=\"128\" height=\"128\" />\n<strong>".$image['name']."</strong>\n<span data-type=\"size\">".$image['shortdesc']."</span></li>\n";
    $count++;
}
```